# can't get a proper number

Tags: c, binary

so, I am making a script that takes in a value and converts it into its binary form.

I am getting the output as some random numbers in an array I can say that I have done something wrong with that `%` things like `%d or %f`.

I have copied the top two functions from another place

```
void rvereseArray(int arr[], int start, int end)
void printArray(int arr[], int size)
```

so here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>


int jo;
int go;

void rvereseArray(int arr[], int start, int end)
{
    int temp;
    while (start < end)
    {
        temp = arr[start]; 
        arr[start] = arr[end];
        arr[end] = temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    } 
}

void printArray(int arr[], int size)
{
int i;
for (i=0; i < size; i++)
    printf("%i ,", arr[i]);

printf("\n");
} 

int decimal(int val)
    {
        int binary[30];
        int count = 0;
        while (val > 1)
        {
            count++;
           float kl = val%2;
           val = val/2;
           binary[count] = kl;
        }
        int n = sizeof(binary) / sizeof(binary[0]);
        rvereseArray(binary,0,n-1);
        printArray(binary,n);

        
        return 0;
    }


int main()
{
    printf("enter that number :");
    scanf("%d",&jo);
    printf("enter your number to be converted :");
    scanf("%d",&go);
    while (go != "k")
    {
        decimal(go);
        printf("you need an another number :");
        scanf("%d",&go);
    }
    
}
```

I have tweaked some of `%d or %f` these

here is my random output

```
enter your number to be converted :31
0 ,0 ,21845 ,1431655456 ,32767 ,-134545464 ,21845 ,1431655533 ,32767 ,-9114 ,32767 ,-9113 ,0 ,194 ,0 ,15774463 ,21845 ,1431650368 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,
you need an another number :
```

thanks.

Comment: You are readin an `int`, but then comparing it to a character. Well, it *could* work by accident, but I doubt the way you would expect. In addition characters go in single quotes. This is even before I got to the actual algorithms.

Comment: What is `jo` for?

Comment: do we have any function like 'append' in c?

Comment: No we don't. Arrays are fixed sizes, you can't append to them.

Comment: jo is actually for using a hexadecimal or any other form, instead of 2 I will be replacing with jo.

Comment: For 32-bit `int` the array `int binary[30];` isn't big enough.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the modulo (number, 2) operation and the successive division of the number over 2 until the number equals 0 and like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,q=1,s=0;
    do
    {
         printf("Give me the number :");
         scanf("%d",&n);
     }while(n<0);
     int temp=n;

     while(n!=0)
     {
         s=s+(n%2)*q;
         q*=10;
         n=n/2;
     }
    printf("\nThe binary form of number %d is :%d\n",temp,s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in the decimal function :

```
int decimal(int val)
{
    char binary[30];  //<= Since you store 1 and 0 a char is sufficient
    int count = 0;
    while (val > 0)
    {
       int kl = val%2; //<= Should be an integer instead of a float
       val = val/2;
       binary[count] = kl;
       count++; //<= Incrementation should be after setting the array
    }
    rvereseArray(binary,0,count-1); //<= No need to compute the length, use count instead
    printArray(binary, count);  //input 31 ===>  1, 1, 1, 1, 1

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yeah it works but there are some minor tweaks '''void rvereseArray(char arr[], int start, int end) // == >changed the arr[] type to char''' and '''void printArray(char arr[], int size) // == >and same for this ''' thanks . hey can you upvote this I don't have any reputitions